# Custom settings.xml in a Maven build on concourse.ci

Tags: maven, build, concourse

I'm building a [concourse](https://concourse-ci.org) pipeline for a Java/Maven project build.
I have succeeded to set it up so that the maven build gets started.
Unfortunately, my own internal Maven dependencies do not get resolved because there is no settings.xml file with the coordinates of our local Artifactory binary repository.

I've seen this [sample project](https://github.com/rjain-pivotal/PCF-demo), which seems to use custom settings.xml, but somehow that setting is commented out.

Can I refer to a custom settings.xml that is located or passed into the Java/Maven build from outside? Which options do I have?

Here is a list of options that came to my mind so far, but all them are suboptimal:

- Put Artifactory repository info into the pom.xml of the project (not portable, in my opinion)
- Build custom Docker image with 1 additional settings.xml file only and use it for the build (lots of efforts and the need to setup a private docker repo just to parameterize 1 setting?)
- Somehow mount the parent/host file system into the container that is used for the build (openjdk:8-jdk in my case) and refer to the settings.xml located in it as shown in the sample project example (how can I do that from concourse?)

Answer (score -1):

I think I found a good way to reach my goal.

The settings.xml can be checked in into the source control system and referenced as resource. It thus becomes accessible at the build time in the container file system (since it is one of the task inputs).

Comment: Thats probably the most effective way to do it, it also follows the concourse versioning paradigm, so the file will be cached on your worker until you change it.